# Merge query to upsert data is always inserting the data when run from .NET 6 Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm encountering an issue with an upsert query in SQL Server within an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. The goal is to check if a record exists and either update It or insert a new one. However, the query consistently inserts new records even when same records already exist in the database.

The strange part is that the query runs fine(inserts and updates) when run from SSMS. But from the API, it only inserts the records even if the record with the same values exists (the database allows duplicate entries).

Any insights into this is greatly appreciated.

Query

```
MERGE SG_APPOINTMENT_DATA AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT '@Appt_ID' AS ApptID, '@OPID' AS OPID) AS SOURCE 
      ON TARGET.ApptID = SOURCE.ApptID 
         AND TARGET.OPID = SOURCE.OPID    

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    
    INSERT ( //Insert )    

WHEN MATCHED THEN     
    UPDATE //update";
```

C# code:

```
 public async Task<int> ExecuteQuery(string query, IDictionary<string, object>? parameters = null)
 {
     int rowsAffected = 0;

     try
     {
         using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         using SqlCommand command = new(query, conn);

         if (parameters != null)
         {
             foreach (var param in parameters)
             {
                 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value));
             }
         }

         await conn.OpenAsync();                

         rowsAffected = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

         await conn.CloseAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: What are the data types for the key values? Is it possible the values are actually different due to something like collation/character encoding, even though they appear to be the same?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple calls. Merge won't protect against that unless you do some locking

Comment: ``SELECT '@Appt_ID' AS ApptID, '@OPID' AS OPID``. You test TARGET.ApptID=``'Appt_ID'`` (literal, not value) then insert @Appt_ID (value). Value 'Appt_Id' not exists in table.

Comment: Parameters cannot be used to "replace" the columns' name.

Comment: The give away is that it works in SSMS, that means something is different when you call it from code. Profile it, and see what the raw SQL you are sending is, and then you will spot the difference.

Comment: `SELECT '@Appt_ID' AS ApptID, '@OPID' AS OPID` should be `SELECT @Appt_ID AS ApptID, @OPID AS OPID`